# URL sin puerto en archivos media utilizando Django-Ngix-Gunicorn en Docker Compose

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-compose, gunicorn

Estoy teniendo un problema utilizando Django REST Framework App en un entorno de docker compose en modo productivo. El problema ocurre cuando un endpoint de la API retorna la ruta de un campo `ImageField` de un modelo, regresa la url sin el puerto del host, con los archivos estaticos no tengo problema.

Ejemplo:

Valor actual: http://127.0.0.1/media/machines/034793bb-8516-45e3-a50a-4e00e7488617.png

Esperado: http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/machines/034793bb-8516-45e3-a50a-4e00e7488617.png

**Settings.py**

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media') 
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/app/static/'
```

** Docker file **

```
FROM python:3.6
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["gunicorn", "-c", "config/gunicorn/conf.py", "--bind", ":8000", "--chdir", 
"app_api.wsgi:application"]
```

**Docker-compose**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web-service:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "pip install -r requirements.txt && python manage.py makemigrations && python 
    manage.py migrate && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput && python manage.py runserver 
    0.0.0.0:8000"
    container_name: app_backend
    volumes:
      - static:/app/static
      - media:/app/media
      - .:/app
    depends_on: 
      - db
    restart: on-failure:2
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: app_postgres
    environment: 
      - POSTGRES_USER=bd_user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=new_database
    ports: 
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes: 
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: on-failure:2
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    volumes: 
      - ./config/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - static:/app/static
      - media:/app/media
    depends_on: 
      - web-service
volumes:
  media:
  static:
  postgres: 
    driver: local
```

**Nginx config file**

```
upstream django_server {
    server web-service:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location /static/ {
        alias /app/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /app/media/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django_server;
        proxy_set_header X-Fowarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

** Gunicorn config **

```
name = 'docker_django'
loglevel = 'info'
errorlog = '-'
accesslog = '-'
workers = 2
```

**Model**

```
class Machine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'machines', default='default.png')
    provider = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    data_source = models.ForeignKey(DataSource, related_name='data_source', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Deberías modificar tu Nginx config y cambiar `$host` por `$http_host`.

```
upstream django_server {
    server web-service:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location /static/ {
        alias /app/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /app/media/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django_server;
        proxy_set_header X-Fowarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host; # modificar esto
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```